# Poor predictive performance for RandomForest in Spark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, random-forest, pyspark

This might be a long shot, but has anybody run into very poor predictive performance using RandomForest with Mllib? Here is what I'm doing:

- Spark 1.4.1 with PySpark
- Python 3.4.2
- ~30,000 Tweets of text
- 12289 1s and 15956 0s
- Whitespace tokenization and then hashing trick for feature selection using 10,000 features
- Run RF with 100 trees and maxDepth of 4 and then predict using the features from all the 1s observations.

So in theory, I should get predictions of close to 12289 1s (especially if the model overfits). But I'm getting exactly 0 1s, which sounds ludicrous to me and makes me suspect something is wrong with my code or I'm missing something. I notice similar behavior (although not as extreme) if I play around with the settings. But I'm getting normal behavior with other classifiers, so I don't think it's my setup that's the problem.

For example:

```
>>> lrm = LogisticRegressionWithSGD.train(lp, iterations=10) 
>>> logit_predict = lrm.predict(predict_feat) 
>>> logit_predict.sum() 
9077 

>>> nb = NaiveBayes.train(lp) 
>>> nb_predict = nb.predict(predict_feat) 
>>> nb_predict.sum() 
10287.0

>>> rf = RandomForest.trainClassifier(lp, numClasses=2, categoricalFeaturesInfo={}, numTrees=100, seed=422) 
>>> rf_predict = rf.predict(predict_feat) 
>>> rf_predict.sum() 
0.0
```

This code was all run back to back so I didn't change anything in between. Does anybody have a possible explanation for this?